# Custom getters for collections within class?

Tags: java

If a class has a collection data structure, maybe a hashmap etc, is it acceptable to use .get(id) within the class to access the collection, or should you write a method which calls the hashmap.get(id)?

I wasn't sure if the getter is more for public access from outside requests?

Comment: Can you give an example of the two ways you're thinking of?

Comment: A class, with a private/protected hashmap.... is it ok to directly call the hashmap's .get() or should you create a getter....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flip the question: Why *wouldn't* you use the hashmap directly?

Ultimately, the answer depends on what you're actually doing. There's zero reason to write a method for getting hash values from *inside* your class unless you actually need to do something other than simply accessing hash values. Your class is the owner of the map–have your way with it.

If you *expose* the map to users of your class, the answer might be different.

Comment: Cool, its just for internal same-class usage

Answer (score 1):

Either is acceptable depending on what you want to do - the best reason I can think of for creating the accessor is that it could be used to maintain invariants - both from within the class and outside - but if you don't need that, just use it directly.

Answer (score -1):

I would return the entire Collection for the client to do with as they see fit.

```
package misc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Misx {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is if your `Misx` class does something with that `List` and needs to be informed when the `List` is modified (e.g. an element added). None of the Java collections fire events so you would require that the users of this class always replace the list when they modify it. You avoid this problem if you do not provide direct access to the `List`